# Android Studio can't import tensorflow lite model (cannot found ml package)

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to make an image classification in Android Studio using tensorflow tflite model. I have upload the model to the project like this

[image: upload model]

And the tflite file sample code said to use like this

[image: sample code]

But i can't import the model. It said

[image: problem]

Is there a solution for this? Thanks

I was trying to use Interpreter, but it deprecated

I've also added this

```
buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
        mlModelBinding true
    }
```

but still can't